# Is there any help for muggle werewolves?

Tags: harry-potter, werewolf, muggles

Since muggles can be turned into werewolves as well, I was wondering I the ministry handles these cases. Questions that come to my mind would be:

- Do the werewolves know of wizards?
- Do the families of children of werewolves know about wizards?
- Do they get a wolfsbane every month?
- Do they have a support center if further questions should come up?

Comment: PS: I decided against splitting because those questions are very interrelated. If a mod still thinks they should be split I'll do it of course xD

Comment: Given the hints at how they treat wizard werewolves, it seems very unlikely they get Wolfsbane on the 'National Health' or a support centre ...

Comment: @Au101 well, but muggles can't help themselves in any way. Wizards werewolves should have some education on werewolves and how to behave of you become one...

Answer (score 6):

**Muggles can be turned into werewolves, but it’s rare.**

The Pottermore [entry for werewolves](http://pottermore.wikia.com/wiki/Werewolves) describes some research into werewolves:

> He also learned from the werewolves that Muggles “taste” different to wizards and that they are much more likely to die of their wounds, whereas witches and wizards survive to become werewolves.

I don’t recall a canon mention of a Muggle werewolf – named werewolves are generally rare in Harry Potter canon, Muggle ones even more so. I imagine it’s unusual enough that the Ministry would treat it on a case-by-case basis (once they stop squabbling over which department should handle it). That gives the Minister of the day discretion to solve the problem as they see fit.

Given their generally low regard for Muggle welfare or way-of-life, I imagine any Muggle werewolves who survive an attack are abducted by the Ministry. Their family get obliviated to believe their relative died in a horrific wolf attack, and secrecy is maintained.

Even if werewolves don’t specifically reveal the existence of wizards, if somebody was found to be a werewolf, it might cause Muggles to start re-opening old myths. That’s unlikely to end well for the magical community.

Comment: Is there any source for low regard of muggle welfare? Because they had a department (OK, it was a small one, but still) which dealt with enchanted muggle artifacts...

Comment: @Armin I’d start with the mass obliviation of any Muggle who crosses paths with magic, regardless of the consequences for their sanity or mental health.

Comment: well, considering that there is an international treaty stating that the magical world should be kept secret, they can't make an exception for every muggle that has problems. furthermore, if they allowed muggles to have knowledge of the wizarding world, they could get into an asylum.

Comment: @Armin - there's also the response to the attack at the world cup (obliviate, and no compensation or further action taken despite the harm).  Or Pettigrew's attack - the crimes they blame him for are betraying the Potters, serving Voldie, and framing Black... the numbers were tossed around for shock value but they quickly disappear.  Or Arhur Weasley's muggle protection act, which 1. was needed, and 2. which failed.

Comment: @Armin - for your second comment, judging by the world cup, and also Hagrid (and Molly) in PS, and Arthur Weasley (really often, for a government specialist) - probably at least three quarters or more of obliviations could be avoided by a good muggle studies class and a talk or three about muggle worthy excuses.  Really, I think the books show they just don't *care*.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding dot three, that of wolfsbane... it is very likely the answer is no, they don't get any.

When we see Remus taking it in PoA, he mentions it is difficult, very complex, and there are few who can make it.  I think he also says he would not get it if Snape hadn't made it for him, perhaps implying it was a perk of the job, but I'm less sure of that.  It might be essential for werewolves to be able to work, but no one seems to be treating it as such... certainly there is no suggestion that it is being given away or subsidized simply because it is a medical necessity.

I assume it is expensive.  Few can make it, that means it's complex enough to drive the price up, even if the ingredients happened to be common.  Even if they somehow had someone willing to make it for free, just for the muggle-born werewolves, there's the price of the ingredients, the potions lab requirements, distribution, and a certain amount of enforcement (so other werewolves didn't sneak onto the list).  I really doubt the ministry would spend money on what they would account charity.  Actually, if they had someone willing to make it, they might lift some of the work restrictions, so they could get the werewolves to pay for the potion (and, profit!).

And the ministry thinks very poorly of muggles (look at the covered up crimes, and general attitude).  The ministry thinks poorly of werewolves (the restrictions, the marginalization, the insults... Umbridge...).  the combination is likely to be treated worse, not better.  I would believe they were kidnapped and everyone else obliviated, as @alexwlchan suggested in his answer.  Or imprisoned, or killed (for breaking rules they had no way of knowing about, even).  I don't think they would get given extra privileges.

For dot four, if they are given support?  I suspect the answer is also no, because the ministry doesn't care, see last paragraph.  Also, what we see of Harry's introduction to the magical world suggests there's not a lot of emphasis on support for muggle-raised - no support center, or resources for learning more, or cultural studies, or even a suggested reading list.  Harry learns a lot more through his friends, which is probably not safe for a government or a school to rely on.  So, I would assume any support or introduction given to muggle werewolves would be equally brief, perhaps a little of where things are and what's expected, and they can sink or swim on their own.

As for your other questions, I'm afraid I don't know the answers - I can't even guess, from what I recall of the books.  I hope you find answers, though, it's interesting now that I've thought about it.